# Plotting contours without transitions in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

let's assume i have three matrices X,Y,Z.

X and Y are created using meshgrid and represent a 2-dimensional grid. Z contains values for this grid which can be either 0, 1 or 2.

Each of these colors represents one color (red, green, and blue). I would like to draw the two dimensional grid using these colors as background. At the moment i am doing this with `contourf`:

```
contourf(X, Y, Z, [0 1 2]);
colormap(bgcolors(1:3,:));
```

The entries 1-3 contain the color information for red, green and blue. The result looks as follows:
[image]

The problem is the small green area on the top of the figure. No value of Z is green in this area (1), but the values on the left are blue (2) and on the right red (0). The `contourf` command instead uses the colormap to draw the transition between the red and blue area. As the green color is between these values in the colormap, the transition is drawn in green.

Is there a better command for drawing such figures? I simply want to have a colored background where the color depends on the value of Z.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your grid is regular (i.e. similar to the output of `meshgrid`), you could also use [`image`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/image.html), [`imagesc`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) or, if the imageprocessing toolbox is available, also [`imshow`](http://www.mathworks.ch/ch/help/matlab/ref/imagesc.html) together with a matching colorscale.

```
imagesc(Z)
```

Comment: Thanks, that works (although the edges are not as nice as above).

Comment: That is true, you just see the raw data. However, the interpolation which gives you smoother contours is essentially also what adds you the unwanted, intermediary green strip...